# In mysql-connector-python I get an error "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" when I run a second query

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I have this error : "2014 (HY000): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

I use mysql-connector-python~=8.0.31

I connected to the database (from a docker container mariaDB latest)
I have created the cursor cur
I Created 4 tables, and when I want to execute any other command as simple as "select 1;"
I get the same error

```
from mysql.connector import connect
conn = connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    user="usr",
    password="pawrd",
    database="databse",
    port="3306"
)
with open("create_tables.sql") as query:
        cur.execute(query.read(), multi= True) # the sql file has all the create statements in one string

cur.execute("select 1") #ERROR
```